# retrieving values with Python's heapq.nlargest() based on first value in tuple

Tags: python, priority-queue

Ultimately, what I want is I'm trying to do is return a list of the top ten 'items' based on their scores.  I am attempting to implement a priority queue of sorts using heapq, and so far what I've got is:

```
class my_queue: 
  # heap-based priority queue for top items
  def __init__(self):
    self.top_items = []

  def push_item(self, item):
    score = item.get_score()
    item_name = item.get_name()
    heapq.heappush(self.top_items, (score, item_name))

  def top_ten(self): 
    top_ten_items = heapq.nlargest(10, self.top_items, key=lambda s: s[0])
    print top_ten_items
```

What I'm doing with `key=lambda s: s[0]` is trying to sort the heap based on `score` from `(score, item_name)`.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this based on the structure I have here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[heapq.nlargest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) is an equivalent to:

```
sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]
```

It means that call `heapq.nlargest(10, self.top_items)` will sort all items again and you will have no benefit of `heap` data structure.

The smallest item in the `heap` can be obtained with [heapq.heappop](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop) function call, since python implementation of `heap` is actually `min heap`.

To get `n` largest items from the `heap` you need to make the largest items the smallest before pushing them into the `heap` (by multiplying -1). For instance, like so:

```
class my_queue: 
    # heap-based priority queue for top items
    def __init__(self):
        self.top_items = []

    def push_item(self, item):
        # minus to make the largest scores the smallest
        heapq.heappush(self.top_items, (-item.get_score(), item))

    def top_ten(self):
        top_ten_items = []
        for i in xrange(10):
            # minus to revert minus in push_item
            large_item = -heapq.heappop(self.top_items)
            top_ten_items.append(large_item)

        print top_ten_items
```